# How to handle asp.net configuration errors

Tags: asp.net, iis

If you publish an ASP.NET app that has an error in the web.config file, ASP.NET won't give you a detailed error message because the app hasn't loaded yet. IIS gives a generic yellow ASP.NET error message, again because the app hasn't loaded, so the debug="true" stuff hasn't been parsed correctly. How can I tell IIS to send the details of the configuration error? As it stands, the only way for me to figure out the problem is to look at the event log on the server itself.

Comment: do you have a problem when you run the project in the debugger?

Comment: No. When I encounter an error of this type, it's usually due to a typo when deploying web.config updates or something of the sort.

Comment: well then copy the web.config from deployment into your project, and run it using the debugger and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I tell IIS to send the details of the configuration error?

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="url" mode="Off">
     <error. . ./>
</customErrors>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx

---

**Update after comments**

*Note, changing this section in the `machine.config` will be the new default for all web applications on the server. To override simply supply this section on your applications' `web.config`.*

Comment: The customErrors property does not work when the web.config file can't be parsed due to errors.

Comment: try changing it in the `machine.config` file

Comment: @Chris nice, thanks for the info. now i know what to do in the future when i have config errors ;)